# Returning a value from a prototype method of a module, synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I have been writing a module to hold an array of objects, and it is supposed to return one of them when provided a specific value. This is done via a prototype method, which can be called from other modules which require it.

The issue I am having is that while this seems like a synchronous method call, the returned object is consistently not the one I am expecting...

To get what I'm trying to do:

```
var ModuleOne = function(){
  this.values = [];
}

ModuleOne.prototype.method = function(value){
  this.values.forEach(function(tempVal){
    if(tempVal.member === value){
      return tempVal;
    }
  });
  return false;
}

module.exports = Module;
```

When I call this method from another module, it always returns `false`, even if it found the desired object.

So my question would be: is a prototype method from another module synchronous in `NodeJS` ? Seems to me like it should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, while writing this question it occured to me where my error lies:

Basically, to answer the question whether a prototype method is synchronous -> Yes, it is.

The problem is that within this method, I am trying to `return` from an anonymous function (`Array.forEach(function(){})`), which of course doesn't do anything since you can't stop a forEach(), and even if you could, would only return to the ongoin prototype method (and in this case go to the next line and simply `return false` every time).

So in order to make this work, I simply need to do the following:

```
ModuleOne.prototype.method = function(value){
  var found = false;

  this.values.forEach(function(tempVal){
    if(tempVal.member === value){
      found = tempVal;
    }
  });
  return found;
}
```

So now it should correctly return the desired object (or false if not found).

Hope this is clears things up !